# MySql: Multiple Queries to select one column from different table

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select * from SC_rules;
+--------+--------+--------+---------------+
| old_SC | new_SC | fee_JD | offer_id_Flag |
+--------+--------+--------+---------------+
|    114 |    111 |  5.000 |             1 | 
|    114 |    310 |  6.000 |             1 | 
|    114 |     41 |  2.000 |             0 | 
+--------+--------+--------+---------------+

mysql> select * from offer_rules;
+--------+--------+----------+-------+
| old_SC | new_SC | offer_id | price |
+--------+--------+----------+-------+
|    114 |    111 |       10 | 1.000 | 
|    114 |    310 |       20 | 0.500 | 
+--------+--------+----------+-------+
```

I want the price from SC_rules where offer_id_Flag =0 and the price from offer_rules where offer_id_flag =1 in once select.

Comment: Post your expected result set

Comment: You have no field called `price` in `SC_rules`.  Desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional `LEFT JOIN` to achieve this, and `COALESCE` to get the first non-`NULL` result.

Something like this (not tested):

```
SELECT  COALESCE(o.price, sc.price)
  FROM  SC_rules sc
    LEFT JOIN offer_rules o ON o.old_SC = sc.old_SC AND sc.offer_id_Flag = 1
```

Basically, get the `price` from your `offer_rules` table (if it exists) otherwise get the `price` from your `sc_rules` table (btw this column seems to be missing from your source data in your question).

The `JOIN` works by matching the rows on the `old_SC` column but you should modify this to whichever column the primary\foreign key is.  The important part is the join on `sc.offer_id_Flag = 1`, which only makes the join when the flag value is 1 (as you want).

Comment: the price column in the SC_rules is the fee_JD

Comment: select CONCAT(SC_rules.new_SC,':',fee_JD)
       from SC_rules 
     where SC_rules.offer_id_Flag =0
    union
     select CONCAT(offer_rules.new_SC,':',price)
          from offer_rules,SC_rules
        where SC_rules.old_SC =offer_rules.old_SC
        and SC_rules.new_SC =offer_rules.new_SC
        and SC_rules.offer_id_Flag =1;

Comment: is the above select is correct, if yes what about performance if I have huge number of rows would it be efficient

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `fee_JD` as 'price' FROM `SC_rules` WHERE `offer_id_Flag`.`SC_rules` = '0';
SELECT `price` FROM `offer_rules` WHERE `offer_id`.`SC_rules` = '1';
```

If you want multi queries.